# SQL Subquery - return specific result

Tags: sql, subquery

*Edited: Changes: completely reworded to more clearly ask my question*

**Problem:** I am trying to update the data.

**Complications:**

1. The table I am updating is: P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM I am inner joining the table to another table (P_FAR_STG_VW.V_CLAIM_60_POLICY_STG) to see what I am missing in the first table.
2. I am updating two fields. 1: Coverage Type Code, which is found in the second table. and 2: Coverage Type Description which is found in a lookup table, based on the Coverage Type Code
3. The problem I am running into is updating the description. The code is easy enough. For example. M = Cancer, F = LTC, etc.

Here is my logic: If the row has a code of M, it is looked up from the table and the field for the description is populated with the correct description.

**QUERY**

> select 
>       P_FAR_SBXD.T_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM.*,
>       P_FAR_STG_VW.V_CLAIM_60_POLICY_STG.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE AS STG_CTC,
>
> (select distinct
>           P_FAR_CR_VW.V_RULE_TRANSLATION_ELEMENT.TRANSLATED_VALUE_TXT,
>           P_FAR_CR_VW.V_RULE_TRANSLATION_ELEMENT.INPUT_VALUE_TXT
>           from
>               P_FAR_CR_VW.V_RULE_TRANSLATION_ELEMENT
>               where P_FAR_CR_VW.V_RULE_TRANSLATION_ELEMENT.INPUT_VALUE_TXT = P_FAR_STG_VW.V_CLAIM_60_POLICY_STG.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE
>               and P_FAR_CR_VW.V_RULE_TRANSLATION_ELEMENT.translation_catg_seq_ID = 510) AS STG_CTD
>
> FROM (inner joins occur here)

My sub query returns too many values, in fact all 16 of the codes and descriptions. How can I link my sub query to my main query to look up what I am looking for?

I hope this was much clearer then the last question.

Comment: No sorry, it is not clear. I notice though, that your sub query has no relation to your outer query; it will find the same value(s) for every record of the main query. Maybe this is what you are looking for? (BTW: You should work with table aliases. That would make your query much more readable.)

Comment: I reworded the entire question. Each row could have a different value then the next one.  How do I tie them together so there is a relationship?

Comment: Sorry, I don't spot the error. In the inner query you select only records where its input_value_txt matches the outer coverage_typ_cde. So it seems impossible that it returns 16 different codes at once rather than the one requested. Do you get an error saying that the subselect returned more than one record? Your subselect retrieves two columns though which is not allowed. I suppose you put it in there when testing and forgot to remove it when posting?